# Random word Bash script if a number is supplied as the first command line argument then it will select from only words with that many characters

Tags: bash, random, centos6

I am trying to create a Bash script that
- prints a random word
- if a number is supplied as the first command line argument then it will select from only words with that many characters.

This is my go at the first section (print a random word):

```
C=$(sed -n "$RANDOM p" /usr/share/dict/words)
echo $C
```

I am really stuck with the second section. Can anyone help?

Comment: Would it help to know that `awk -v n=6 'length($0) == n'  /usr/share/dict/words` shows only words of length 6?

Answer (score 1):

might help someone coming from ryans tutorial

```
#!/bin/bash

charlen=$1
grep -E "^.{$charlen}$" $PWD/words.txt | shuf -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a while loop to read every single line of that file and check if the length of a word equals the specified number ( including apostrophes ). In my o.s it is 99171 line ( i.e the file).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 readWords() {
    declare -i int="$1"

    (( int == 0 )) && {
       printf "%s\n" "$int is 0, cant find 0 words"
       return 1
    }

    while read getWords;do
       if [[ ${#getWords} -eq $int ]];then
         printf "%s\n" "$getWords"
       fi
   done < /usr/share/dict/words
}

readWords 20
```

this function takes a single argument. the `declare` command coerces the argument into an integer, if the argument is a string , it coerces it into a number which is 0 . Since we don't have 0 words if the specified argument ( number ) is 0 ( or a string coerced to 0 ) return from the function.

Read every single line in /usr/share/dict/words, get the length of each line with `${#getWords}` ( `$#` >> gives the length of a string/commandline parameters/array size ) check if it equals the specified argument ( number )

Comment: It's strange because the tutorial I am following, has only discussed the introduction and variables, and is now asking me to perform this task. The tutorial later discusses loops.
Is there not a way of doing this without a while loop?

Comment: using awk? using awk in a while loop?

Comment: using awk in a while loop to solve this problem is overkill. But you can still use awk to solve this problem. Since you asked "how to do it in bash" , you have to use a loop

Answer (score 0):

This code would achieve what you want:

```
awk -v n="$1" 'length($0) == n' /usr/share/dict/words > /tmp/wordsHolder
shuf -n 1 /tmp/wordsHolder
```

**Some comments**: by using `"$RANDOM"` (as you did on your original script attempt), one would generate an integer on the range `0 - 32767`, which could be more (or less) than the number of words (lines) available, given the desired number of characters on a word -- thus, potential for errors here.

To avoid that, we are using a `shuf` syntax that will retrieve a (sub)randomly picked word (line) on the file using its entire range (from `line 1 - last line of file`).

Answer (score 0):

A loop is not required, you can do something like

```
CH=$1; # how many characters the word must have
WordFile=/usr/share/dict/words; # file to read from
# find how many words that matches that length
TOTW=$(grep -Ec "^.{$CH}$" $WordFile);
# pick a random one, if you expect more than 32767 hits you
#  need to do something like ($RANDOM+1)*($RANDOM+1)
RWORD=$(($RANDOM%$TOTW+1));
#show that word
grep -E "^.{$CH}$" $WordFile|sed -n "$RWORD p"
```

Depending on things you probably need to add checks for things like that $1 is a reasonable number, the file exist, that TOTW is >0 and so on.